# Elasticsearch filter on multiple nested paths

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have an ES index with nested data which is mapped like this

```
"mappings": {
    "voertuig": {
        "properties": {
            "vestiging": {
                "properties": {
                    "name_dtc": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                "type": "nested"
            },
            "accessoires": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "fields": {
                            "raw": {
                                "index": "not_analyzed",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to create a query that **filters** on both (raw) values. I am able to create a filter that filters on one of these values, like this:

```
   {
        "body": {
            "post_filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "vestiging.name_dtc.raw": "Location X"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "vestiging"
                }
            },
            "query": {
                "match_all": { }
             }
        },
        "index": "ocm",
        "type": "voertuig"
    }
```

However, what I need is something like this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "post_filter": {
            "nested": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "accessoires.name.raw": "Climate Control"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "opties"
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "vestiging.name_dtc.raw": "Location X"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "vestiging"
                }
            ]
        },
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "key": "33e75ff09dd6"
                    }
                },
                "query": []
            }
        }
    },
    "index": "ocm",
    "type": "voertuig"
}
```

The first query works the second one raises an error:

> nested: QueryParsingException[[ocm] [nested] filter does not support [null]];

How would I go about creating a filter that matches fields in multiple paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "nested": {
                "filter": {
                  "term": {
                    "accessoires.name.raw": "Climate Control"
                  }
                },
                "path": "accessoires"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "filter": {
                  "term": {
                    "vestiging.name_dtc.raw": "Location X"
                  }
                },
                "path": "vestiging"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "key": "33e75ff09dd6"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think the problem you are having is a result of incorrect usage of the nested filter although it is a bit difficult to get the exact problem from the exception message.  Essentially if you want to combine two nested filters, you will have to group them using `bool` or `and` filters.

I have reduced the query quite a bit for the sake of a smaller post.  I do not have the `post_filter` since you don't have any aggregations in your example.  I replaced the inner bool filters with just the single term filter that they have and tagged on that additional key (`term`) filter.  But you can continue using your query structure and expand it as you need with the main fix addressing how the two nested filters are put together.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. It is much simpler than I could have guessed.  So I can basically use any other filter inside my bool filter?

Comment: Yep.  Everything in the list of must clauses will be satisfied.  If you haven't already looked at the bool query docs, there are must_not, should clauses also available to help you combine queries.